# Getting keyname of parent

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
this.doStuff({
    'testkey': {
        testfunction: function() {
            // will return testfunction
            console.log(Object.keys(this));
        }
    }
});
```

Is there are a way of getting `testkey` within the testfunction scope?

The `Object.keys(this)` will return `testfunction`.

Comment: `Object.keys(object)`

Comment: @AndréDion thanks. that works for my example. but what if the object is a parameter for a function and doesnt have name?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example that more closely matches your problem?

Comment: I may be wrong by I have the impression that there's no link for the internal function to the external object that you can use.

Comment: I changed the example, thank you again

Comment: Is your example intended to convey that you are passing an anonymous object (containing `'testKey': {...}`) as an argument to the `this.doStuff()` function?

Comment: yes. that example is exactly what I use. Only the names are different.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `this` keyword is a bit of an unusual beast — it's going to change depending on how a function is called, and most of the time, `this` will refer to the function it's inside. In this scenario, that's just `testfunction`, so naturally it's going to give you only the results local to that function.

There's various tutorials on understanding **this** available:

- Here on Stack Overflow: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/254830)
- QuirksMode: [The `this` keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
- Mozilla Developer Network: [`this` operator reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

---

In your scenario, [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) takes an object and returns its keys. If you want the keys of your `object`, you need to give it that (I've renamed your variables though):

```
var foo = {
    'key': {
        func: function() {
            console.log(Object.keys(foo)); // <------
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

if you know which method to call inside the javascript object, then you can do so.

You can preserve the scope of caller using apply or call method

```js
function doStuff(ob){
  ob[Object.keys(ob)]['testfunction'].call(ob);
}

doStuff({
    'testkey': {
        testfunction: function() {
            // will return testkey
            console.log(Object.keys(this));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply can do :

```
var object = {
    'testkey': {
        testfunction: function() {
            // will return testfunction
            console.log(Object.keys(object));
        }
    }
};
```

because inside the function scope you can see the global var 'object'